# Booting MacOS Big Sur from USB not working (MacBook Pro mid 2015)

Tags: big-sur, bootable-disk

Have created a bootable USB installer according to these instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 for my MacBook Pro mid 2015 (A1398).

Pressed Option key while booting, selected the USB flash disk with the Big Sur installation on it, but still it ends up with a crossed circle.

Where can I see the USB boot logs? It becomes so annoying.

Comment: On which hardware are you trying to boot from USB?

Comment: @nohillside MacBook Pro A1398 mid 2015, supported by BigSur (actually USB was created directly on it)